# Identifying O-rings with a low friction ratio

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pumps

I want to make a precision syringe pump and need some O-rings for its piston. The cylinder is made of stainless steel (maybe later I'll order a glass one). The lower the friction ratio, the better the precision of the pump.

What sort of rubber is the best in this case? BuNa? Viton? Silicone? Something else?

Also, what should be used to keep it lubricated?

Comment: Do any of those materials listed have friction coefficients for the glass/metal cylinder material? Is there anything special about the fluid that would react with certain materials? i.e. solvent, acidic, basic, hot, cold, etc.

Comment: You can get PFTE-coated o-rings which are supposed to be self-lubricating, see for example [these](http://www.par-group.co.uk/sealing-and-jointing/o-rings-and-mechanical-seals/ptfe-encapsulated-o-rings/).

Comment: The fluid will be simple or distilled water. No acid, no fuel, nothing aggressive. Also, the ring should be rather small: its outer diameter will be only 6 mm.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using [quad-rings](http://www.mnrubber.com/Design_Guide/6-3.html) (sometimes called X profile o-rings) instead of o-rings.  I worked and a mechanical engineer for a packaging machinery company that created a lot of piston filler machines with stainless steel barrels and Delrin pistons.  The seals were always quad rings.

McMaster Carr has a [wide variety](http://www.mcmaster.com/#o-rings) of o-rings available, including X profile o-rings with sizes down to 3mm ID x 6mm OD.

Answer (score 1):

To my answer of metal o ring...
Non-vented rings (OI & OE) are designed for lower pressure ranges. The perfectly closed O Ring design avoids ingress of the media into the seal. Moderate load, moderate pressure capability.
Internally (OVI) or externally (OVE) vented O Rings are designed for higher pressure. Besides the own seating load the seal is also energised by the system pressure.
Spring-energised metal O Ring for Internal pressure (OSI) and (OSE) for external pressure are designed for extreme low leakage at moderate pressures.
Gas filled metal O Ring for high temperature and moderate pressure applications. OGI for internal pressure and OGE for external pressure.

For more details plz visit :
http://www.htmsfutom.com/

Answer (score 0):

From experience designing and testing mechanical seals, I'll tell you straight up that it can vary a huge amount based mainly on several factors.

- The squeeze on the o-ring
- The surface finish of the sliding surface
- O-ring material
- Lubrication

At the sizes you're talking, squeeze on the o-ring would be my biggest concern. It will change due to variations in the o-rings themselves. Designing o-ring grooves properly, especially that small can be a challenge.

With stainless steel, you'll want as smooth a surface finish as you can get.

For lubrication, it will depend on the application and what contaminants are tolerable, but for many applications, we use an inert white grease, [Krytox](https://www.chemours.com/Lubricants/en_US/products/Products_Greases.html). It's expensive but worth it.

I would start with a basic Viton o-ring lubricated with krytox grease, that is my go-to starting point. Unless there's some compelling reason, such as you can't tolerate any contamination whatsoever, then I'd consider a PTFE o-ring or a coated/impregnated o-ring but they get pricey fast too and the available sizes are limited.

For designing these kind of dynamic seals, I'd start with the [Parker O-ring handbook](http://parker.com/portal/site/PARKER/menuitem.6c94058cc6466c6315731910237ad1ca/?vgnextoid=a141a35c7575e210VgnVCM10000048021dacRCRD&vgnextfmt=default) and design your cylinder/piston around a standard size using their recommendations. While you *can* get custom o-rings made, it's almost never worth it unless your production volumes will be very, very large.

Answer (score 0):

Best used for metal o ring :

Gas filled metal O Ring for high temperature and moderate pressure applications. OGI for internal pressure and OGE for external pressure.

In oil and gas applications metal seals are highly preferred. In applications like deep sea where the pressures are extreme and the environment is corrosive special seals are made. At times they are gold plated for excellent performance. In power generation these seals are used to seal various parts of turbine section.

Type of seals used:

- Metal O-ring - Shaped as well as circular seals.
- C-ring - Shaped as well as circular seals.
- Spring energized C-rings - Shaped as well as circular seals.
- Radial / CA seals – circular in shape.

click here more information about metal o rings

http://htmsfutom.com/metal-o-ring-manufacturer.php

https://www.facebook.com/futomengineerspvtltd/